# How do I change the text color of text in powershell?

Tags: powershell, text, colors

I am running into an issue where blue text almost identical to the default background appears and it becomes quite difficult to read. Does anyone know how to change this blue color to something a bit more readable?

[image: PowerShell Text]

I have gone through the properties/ color tab in PowerShell, but none of the settings here are set this blue color.

Comment: do you see any function named `prompt` in your `$profile` file?

Comment: It happened to me too, the settings were not stored. A bit off topic, using  Windows Terminal this  doesn't happen

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon where do I find the profile file I checked \WindowsPowerShell\v1.0, but it is not present here

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, you can right-click on the terminal and click Preferences and change the color scheme.

If you are on Windows and are using [Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/windowsterminal), click the little downwards arrow next to the +.[image] Click Settings, then Windows Power Shell in the bottom left[image]

then Scroll down to "Appearance" And here you can customize your shell. You can change color scheme, add a background image, change font, everything you need.